# iText7 - correct way to build an AcroForm field hierarchy

Tags: itext, itext7

iText 7.0.0

is there a way to build a field hierarchy in iText7 without manipulating the Fields dictionary directly?  Although PdfFormField has setParent / addKid methods, i haven't found the right combination/sequence of AcroForm.addField and setParent/addKid that can produce (hopefully this syntax makes sense):

```
/Fields [(
     /T root 1 0 ("empty" field)
     /Kids [(
          /T child 2 0 ("empty" field)
          /Parent 1 0
          /Kids [(
               /T text1   (text widget)
               /FT Txt
               /Type /Annot
               /Subtype /Widget
               /Parent 2 0
          )]
      )]
 )]
```

i.e. a field named `root.child.text1`

the closest i've come (which doesn't work for certain indirectRef scenarios) is

```
    PdfFormField root = PdfFormField.createEmptyField(doc);
    root.setFieldName("root");
    form.addField(root, null);
    PdfFormField child = PdfFormField.createEmptyField(doc);
    child.setFieldName("child");
    form.addField(child, null);
    root.addKid(child);
    PdfTextFormField text1 = PdfFormField.createText(doc, new Rectangle(100, 700, 200, 20), "text1", "");
    // any rendered field needs to be added to the form BEFORE parent 
    // is set, otherwise an exception is thrown in processKids()
    form.addField(text1);
    child.addKid(text1);
    // cleanup the Fields dict
    PdfArray rootFields = form.getPdfObject().getAsArray(PdfName.Fields);
    rootFields.remove(text1.getPdfObject());
    rootFields.remove(child.getPdfObject());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to approach in the following way. This code works for me, at least in the current 7.0.1-SNAPSHOT version, and therefore it will work in 7.0.1, which is in weeks to come.

You don't have to add each field to the form directly. According to the specification, only root fields, i.e. the ones that have no ancestors, have to be added to the form. Their descendants are taken into account automatically.

```
PdfFormField root = PdfFormField.createEmptyField(pdfDoc);
root.setFieldName("root");

PdfFormField child = PdfFormField.createEmptyField(pdfDoc);
child.setFieldName("child");
root.addKid(child);

PdfTextFormField text1 = PdfFormField.createText(pdfDoc, new Rectangle(100, 700, 200, 20), "text1", "test");
child.addKid(text1);

form.addField(root);
```

Comment: ok...by not calling form.addField() on non-root fields does in fact _construct_ the PDF correctly (which *was* my question), but the following assertion ends up failing because the AcroForm's fields collection isn't properly updated `assertThat(form.getFormFields().size(), is(3)); // fails - size == 1`

Comment: also..i still haven't fully grasped the differences between a document being actively written and one that's been closed() (completed), but is it possible and would it make sense for every call to getFormFields() to use the field dictionary (i.e. create the Map on the fly) vs. a Map instance on the PdfAcroForm (created on getAcroForm())?

Comment: The fact that `form.getFormFields()` did not return proper result was a bug which is now fixed in `7.0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: As for generating the field map on the fly, this is an expensive operation which we really want to avoid.